# Firebase error: Permission denied. Unable to read/write from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I need to give read/write access only to authenticated users, but it seems like Firebase is not recognizing that the user is authenticated.

After I sign in the user with email and password, I am assuming user is authenticated and should be allowed to read/write from database. However permission is denied.

Here is the code for sign in activity:

```
 firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            //checking if success
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                //display some message here
                // Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                sRef.authWithPassword(email,password,new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, user.getDisplayName()+" is authenticated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    }
                });

                Intent i = new Intent(Register.this,MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(i);

            }else{
                //display some message here
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

I want to use the default rule in firebase that allows only auth users to read/write from database:

```
{
 "rules": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
 ".write": "auth != null"
}
}
```

But when I change the rules as below my code is able to get read/write access to database.

```
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write":true
}
}
```

This is fine in testing, however I cannot continue with production with this method. Please help, how to authenticate a registered user to access database in Firebase.

Comment: None of the code you shared accesses the database, so it can't be raising that error yet. Please share the [minimum, complete code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you enable firbase sign in method like email/password or anonymous in auth section before login.

Comment: I did not share the code for accessing firebase database, as it is working but only when i change the rules to public. When I use the default rules, the permission is denied.

Comment: @DhavalkumarSolanki  Yes I have done both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is a mixture of API calls from the legacy 2.x.x. SDK, for example:

`sRef.authWithPassword(email,password,new Firebase.AuthResultHandler()`

and the new 9.x.x SDK:

`firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()`

The two SDKs are not compatible.  You need to use or the other. The [Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android) explains how to migrate from the legacy SDK to the new SDK.

You also need to use the Firebase console that corresponds to the SDK used: [Legacy Console](https://www.firebase.com/login/) or new [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

Comment: I did try with removing: sRef.authWithPassword(email,password,new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() but it still don't work. That was the first thing I did.

Comment: I got it working, All I had to do was update android studio repositories and add the new dependencies. Thank you.